# Как правильно сделать foreach?

Tags: php, mysql

*Сразу извиняюсь если вопрос глупый, возможно я не так гуглил.*

У меня есть комментарии в БД.

comments ->

-> id (уник. id комментария)

--> page_id (страницы на которой был оставлен комментарий)

--> text_comment (текст комментария)

Я вывожу комментарии следующим образом:

```
  <?php
  $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `films` WHERE `id` = " . (int) $_GET['id']);
  $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
  $page_id = $rows['id']; // уникальный id фильма
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123", "db");// Подключается к базе данных
    $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `page_id`='$page_id'"); //Вытаскиваем все комментарии для данной страницы
    while ($rows = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
      print_r($rows); //Вывод комментариев
      echo "<br>";
    }
  ?>
```

Выводятся данные массива:

```
 Array ( [id] => 1 [page_id] => 1 [text_comment] => ппц. напишут тупой вопрос) 

Array ( [id] => 2 [page_id] => 1 [text_comment] => тебя в гугле забанили? )
```

Мне нужно, чтобы данные выводились просто комментариями, просто текстом, без всяких array => и прочего.

Я знаю, что перебрать массив нужно с помощью foreach или for.

Но допустим я делаю:

```
$rows = $result_set->fetch_assoc();
  for ($i=0; $i < count($rows) ; $i++) {
    echo $rows;
  }
```

И выводиться ArrayArrayArray учитывая то, что на данный момент у меня 2 комментария, хотя бы просто ArrayArray выводилось бы...

Comment: `foreach($rows as $row){ echo $row['text_comment']; }`

Comment: У меня ошибка. Что с $rows = $result_set->fetch_assoc(); делать?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Выборка комментариев из БД:

```
<?php

$comments = [];
$query = "SELECT * FROM ...";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
  /* извлечение ассоциативного массива */
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $comments[] = $row;
  }

  /* удаление выборки */
  $result->free();
}

/* Использование итераторов (поддержка была добавлена начиная с PHP 5.4) */
// foreach ($result = $mysqli->query($query) as $row ) {
//   $comments[] = $row;
// }

?>
```

Вывод комментариев:

```
<?php if (empty($comments)): ?>
  <p>Комментариев нет.</p>
<?php else: ?>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
      <li>
        <?= $comment['text_comment'] ?>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!

Comment: Забавно.. В комментах то же самое +2, а в ответах -2

Comment: @РустамГимранов да мне не принципиально.. Просто автор отметил ответ, значит работает и минуса... Ну так-то я вот щас понял что там же в продолжении автора можно просто вот так сделать -> `while ($rows = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo $rows['text_comment'];
    }` Тупить стал.. Пора в отпуск

Comment: @РустамГимранов Да, редактируйте что хотите. Но теперь то я понял откуда минуса, но не понятно почему плюсы в комментарии теперь) Ну нет чтоб написать хоть что не так.. Хз.. я всегда пишу причину, если приходится минусовать

Comment: @РустамГимранов не стоит редактировать настолько кривые ответы. Лучше написать свой. А еще луче оставить как есть. Ни автору вопроса, ни автору ответа никакие правки не помогут.

Comment: @Ипатьев Правильно, в любой непонятной ситуации - скатываемся к оскорблениям. Так держать